# Formato numérico en notación científica en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando dar formato a los numeros de una "colorbar" con notación científica:

`cbar = fig.colorbar(pcm, format = '%.1E', shrink = 0.9)`

de manera que lo que obtengo es, por ejemplo:

`3.0E02`

Y yo quiero quitar el "0"(cero) del exponente

`3.0E02 -> 3.0E2`

Gracias

Comment: Podrías aclarar que modulo estás usando por favor? No podemos responderte si no sabemos que usas. De paso podrías añadir la etiqueta relacionada a dicho modulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las sintaxis de las cadenas de formato soportadas por python (`%.1E` por ejemplo) no te permite eliminar ese cero en la parte del exponente.

Pero puedes escribir una función que lo haga y pasársela a matplotlib. La función que escribas recibirá dos parámetros: el número a representar y la posición en que se hará (lo segundo lo podemos ignorar).

Así que podemos escribir una función como esta, que convierte el dato numérico en cadena usando el formato estándar `.1E`, para después dividir la cadena en dos partes por la "E" y convertir el exponente a entero, lo que elimina el cero inicial, y después junta de nuevo las dos partes en una cadena:

```
def myfmt(n, pos):
  s = "{:.1E}".format(n)
  mantisa, exponente = s.split("E")
  exponente = int(exponente)
  return "{}E{}".format(mantisa, exponente)
```

Puedes usar esta función en un plot del siguiente modo:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax = plt.subplot()
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(2500).reshape((50, 50)))
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, format=ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt))
```

La línea que interesa es la última, el resto es solo para crear unos datos de ejemplo a graficar. El resultado:

[image: Resultado]

### Bonus

La posibilidad de crear tu propia función de formato como acabamos de hacer, abre nuevas posibilidades, ya que si la cadena que retornas está encerrada en dólares, se considerará una fórmula LaTeX. De este modo puedes cambiar la E por un verdadero 10 elevado al exponente:

```
def myfmt(n, pos):
  s = "{:.1E}".format(n)
  mantisa, exponente = s.split("E")
  exponente = int(exponente)
  return "${}\\times10^{{{}}}$".format(mantisa, exponente)
```

Y la gráfica resultante sería ahora:

[image: Usando latex]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!